# LUKS on Ubuntu 16.04 : unknown filesystem type 'crypto_LUKS'

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, luks, dm-crypt

I'm using (L)Ubuntu 16.04. I would like to backup my files on an external hard drive (sdd) with LUKS. There was no partition (sdd1, etc.) before the cryptsetup command.

```
#sudo cryptsetup -v --cipher aes-xts-plain64 --key-size 512 --hash sha512 --iter-time 2000 --use-random --verify-passphrase luksFormat /dev/sdd
```

Passphrase ok. It worked. But then :

```
#sudo mount /dev/sdd /mnt/
mount: unknown filesystem type 'crypto_LUKS'
```

How can it be unknown filesystem, as I used it just before ?

Thanks

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/63594/mount-encrypted-volumes-from-command-line

Answer (score 15):

To be able to access your files you have to decrypt them first

```
cryptsetup open /dev/sda1 backup
```

where sda1 is the encrypted partition and backup is the name of your partition (that is a very basic command, you can fix it according to your needs). Then type your password, and proceed to mount that unencrypted using

```
mount /dev/mapper/backup /mnt
```

Done! now visit the mounted partition

```
cd /mnt/backup
```

Comment: I have to say my HDD has no name. So, I arbitrarily call it  "backup" below, and it works.
And it has zero partition : there is no "sdb1" or "sdb2", there is only "sdb".

`~$ sudo cryptsetup open /dev/sdb backup
Enter passphrase for /dev/sdb: 
~$ sudo mount /dev/mapper/backup /mnt
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/backup,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.`

Comment: you might have a bad Superblock. Check this https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1245536&p=7822694#post7822694 and come back

Comment: You're right : ~$ e2fsck -f /dev/sdd1
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
e2fsck: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
Resize inode not valid.  Recreate<y>? yes
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes […]Inode 14028290, i_size is 2529966949950002624, should be 0.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 14028290, i_blocks is 74937487465024, should be 0.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 14028302 has illegal block(s).  Clear<y>? yes
Illegal block #0 (1002589455) in inode 14028302.  CLEARED.
[…] ad nauseam... I tried it with another hdd. Is it a LUKS bug ?

Comment: Don't think so. I guess your HDD is beginning to fail. Save your data and move it you other HDD. Let me know if you were able to fix the issue so I can update the answer so then you can accept it.

Comment: I tried with another HDD again. Same problem. Note : I can encrypt my HDD with gnome-disks, but this is not a solution : I want sha512.

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have not enough rep to comment on @Joe's succinct answer.

For me, something that took too long to work out was that the first command in Joe's answer resulted in the mapping `/dev/mapper/backup` to be created, and that is what needs to be mounted, hence `mount /dev/mapper/backup /mnt`

I had troubles as the drive was already mounted, but I wanted to remount it, so for unmounting I did not know the mapping name, I could have found it in the `/dev/mappings` directory

I finally managed to work out how to unmount with this command `umount /dev/mapper/FALCON_1` (FALCON_1 being the peculiar name of where my HDD was mapped)

Hope it helps someone.